# Checking for inequality against string variable fails

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have the code like this:

```
var query = repository.Where(item => item.UserId == userId && item.LoanNumber != loanNumber)
```

which is transformed to SQL (repository is IQueryable).

loanNumber is a string parameter in the method. The problem is that checking against inequality fails (ignored). If instead of variable I use constant with its value, it works properly.

What the... ?

Comment: what is the constant value that you used? You can also check using sql profiler the difference between using constant and variable..

Comment: it was "999999"-kind string. As to SQL profiler - I'm afraid I cannot use it, as far as I understand it's MS SQL server tool? And we use Oracle.

Comment: You can still use [ef logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx) to see the generated query

Comment: Sorry, it had to do with spaces. DB stores some columns with padding and despites the magic in the code, since I am not allowed to change this lousy DB, I might be missed some stuff. Applying the trim to LoanNumber helped. But of course I will try to investigate this issue further.

Answer (score 0):

A number should be a `NUMBER` DATA TYPE, and not a string. It violates normalization rules. So please tell what are the data type of the values being compared on both sides of the expression in predicate.

If you compare similar data types, you would get correct results as you don't and should not rely on implicit conversion.

So make sure you have the correct data type.